# Spring library with Service provider login page

Tags: spring, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a requirement that needs to have login page at the service provider and I use java web app. Is there any way to use the spring SAML libraries to achieve this behaviour ? If so, what could be the steps? (it seems the default behavior of spring library is to redirect to IDP login page and I am not sure if we can configure to host login page on the service provider and relay that request to IDP)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is having two different ways to authenticate, one locally and one through SAML.  I believe for having a login form, you would want to separate configurations with different AuthenticationEntryPoints, i.e. go to `/login` for local or `/saml/login/alias/" + spAlias+ "?idp=" + spEntityID` for direct login to SAML.

It sounds like right now you have SAML protecting any URL, which by default redirects you to the IDP since it's configured.  The first step that I would take is getting user name and password authentication working with logins independently of SAML, then add SAML back in. Be sure to list whatever URL the login form uses as permit all so SAML doesn't kick in.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, to clarify, my requirement is that there is only one login page but that resides on the SP and not use the IDP's login page. I wonder if there is a spring configuration change to use the spring SAML extension.

Comment: I don't think there is and here is why.  If you have the user enter the username and password for another application's IDP, then you could store that information and gain access as that any other application that IDP protects.  In order to avoid this, the SAML workflow redirects you to the IDP where the credentials can be entered securely.  Then sends a signed response back to the SP.